# present walkthrough scenes only once ios swift

Tags: ios, swift

I created a PageViewController and added three view controllers as a walkthrough for my app, but i want them to be displayed only once, and i can't figure out how.

here is my code for the pageViewController:

```
import UIKit

class MyPageViewController: UIPageViewController{

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  dataSource = self
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    if let firstViewController = orderedViewControllers.first {
        setViewControllers([firstViewController],
                           direction: .Forward,
                           animated: true,
                           completion: nil)
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
//array for the ordered view controllers
private(set) lazy var orderedViewControllers: [UIViewController] = {
    return [self.newColoredViewController("First"),
            self.newColoredViewController("Second"),
            self.newColoredViewController("Third")]
}()

private func newColoredViewController(color: String) -> UIViewController {
    return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil) .
        instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("\(color)ViewController")
}

}

 extension MyPageViewController: UIPageViewControllerDataSource {
//returning index of previous view controller
func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
                        viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    guard let viewControllerIndex = orderedViewControllers.indexOf(viewController) else {
        return nil
    }

    let previousIndex = viewControllerIndex - 1

    guard previousIndex >= 0 else {
        return nil
    }

    guard orderedViewControllers.count > previousIndex else {
        return nil
    }

    return orderedViewControllers[previousIndex]
}
//returning index of the next view controller
func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
                        viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    guard let viewControllerIndex = orderedViewControllers.indexOf(viewController) else {
        return nil
    }

    let nextIndex = viewControllerIndex + 1
    let orderedViewControllersCount = orderedViewControllers.count

    guard orderedViewControllersCount != nextIndex else {
        return nil
    }

    guard orderedViewControllersCount > nextIndex else {
        return nil
    }

    return orderedViewControllers[nextIndex]
}

}
```

how do i edit the code to display it only once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you've said I'm guessing that you only want it to show the first time the user opens the app and then not appear again?

Theres a few ways of doing this, the simplest would likely be to set a property on NSUserDefaults, this will remember the setting in between app launches. try something like:

```
// this should be your initial view controller
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if !defaults.boolForKey("walkthroughSeen") {
        // create page view controller and display
        let walkthroughVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).
    instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MyPageViewController")
        self.presentViewController(walkthroughVC, animated: true)

        defaults.setBool(true, forKey: "walkthroughSeen")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You that's what i needed. :)